# dc.js: Adding a Legend to Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, dc.js

I'm trying to add a legend to my pie chart but I keep getting the error `TypeError: dc.legend is not a function`.

I'm not sure where to begin on fixing this. I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459683/add-legend-to-pie-chart-in-dc-js) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189840/pie-chart-legend-in-dc-js-1-7-not-showing-up), but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var geoValue = facts.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.geo;
});
var geoGroup = geoValue.group();


geoChart
    .width(480)
    .radius(100)
    .innerRadius(90)
    .dimension(geoValue)
    .group(geoGroup)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(250).y(100)) //LEGEND CODE
    .title(function(d){return d.geo;});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax looks correct.

I have had several cases where my legend did not show up either.  It was usually because I specified .x() or .y() outside the container size of the graph.  Start by putting the legend at .x(0).y(0) to make sure it fits inside the container.

A working fiddle of the basic .legend() for the pieChart can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/za8ksj45/39/

```
    Working example of original .legend(): line 1018
    Working example of new .legend2(): line 1030
```

It is a bit lengthy because the example includes a modification to legend.js in the beginning of the  section that lets you add (%) to it.   If you just need the standard legend, look at line 1018.

Comment: Glad it was useful.  Just out of curiosity, are you are using the (%) 'feature'?